# How can I buy black pepper with mainly black bits?

Tags: pepper

When buying black pepper I notice it usually comes whole or grounded but it usually contains the outer black part as well as the inner white part hence a mixture of white and black bits.  When fine grounded it looks grey.

I prefer the taste of the black bits only however they dont seem to be sold with the black bits only.
How can I make it seperating the white and black bits and can I buy it like that also?  Do I have to search for a particular term because I can only found whole or ground both of which conain white and black bits.

Comment: Actually dried peppercorn is black on the outside (pericarp) due to oxidation and white on the inside. White pepper is the same black pepper but pericarp is removed with a water bath. Ground black pepper conteins both black and white parts as there are no means of keeping just the pericarp.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/97489/67 ;

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is possible.  For the best flavor, buy whole peppercorns from a reputable source and grind yourself in small amounts.  You might even enjoy the flavor more if you toast the peppercorns lightly in a pan before grinding.

Comment: If white pepper is black pepper with the skin removed, surely it can and is removed in processing? I’m not expecting it to be completely free if any white colour, just a lot blacker then what you get after a typical coarse grind.

Comment: Yes, both are fruits of the same plant, but they are processed differently. The black outer layer happens because they are picked ripe and sun dried.  As you write, the outer layer is removed to produce white pepper.  However, I have never heard of, nor seen, the black layer only being packaged and/or sold.   I guess the ultimate question for me is, what is it that you are looking to achieve?  Is this a color quest or a flavor quest?